# Datagrid itemssource and binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

```
class Order
{
    public string StockName         { get; set; }
    public decimal PurchasePrice    { get; set; }
}

class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Order> OrderList { get; set; }
}

var AccountList = new ObservableCollection<Account>()
{
    new Account(){Name= "Acc1", OrderList = new ObservableCollection<Order>() { new Order(){ StockName="IBM", PurchasePrice=20.00m}}},
    new Account(){Name= "Acc2", OrderList = new ObservableCollection<Order>() { new Order(){ StockName="IBM", PurchasePrice=21.00m}, new Order(){ StockName="YHOO", PurchasePrice=6.00m}}}
};
```

Assume I have the classes and data repository listed above. I would like a datagrid that outputs the average purchase price in each cell, with the columns corresponding to the account name, and the rows to the stockname. I can do this with code-behind theoretically, but I am using an MVVM approach and am having trouble setting up the properties and bindings that would accomplish what I need to do, with the main issues being that the number and name of accounts is not known, and the order history will always be changing.

The intended datagrid would look something like this:

```
             Acc1     Acc2  
IBM      |    20    |    21  |    
YHOO     |    0     |    6   |
```

My initial thought was to create a concatenated order List, and then use a group by function to group it by stockname, but at that point I am not sure how to populate the data by column(Account).

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: How do you want to display data. like Name & Average(PurchasePrice). It is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to process your current data and place it into a structure that matches the way you want to output it. So you need to end up with a collection of entries where each entry is a stock.  Then within each stock entry you want the same collection of all accounts. Each account entry would be the average purchase price for that clients purchase of that stock. Many will be zero because the account has not bought any of that stock.

Now it becomes easier because you can bind your collection of stock entries to the data grid and each stock becomes a row. Then you setup your data grid columns so that each column references the named account from the row.

Comment: Right, but how do you set up the columns without doing it explicitly either in the XAML or the reprocessed data for the datagrid?

Comment: I think you need to do it explicitly in code, because the set of columns is dynamic.